# How can I use Perl extract a particular column from a tab-separated file?

Tags: perl

I am really new at Perl and have been trying to piece together a solution for this.  When I run this program I don't get any errors and it doesn't display anything.

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (DATA, "<test1.txt") or die ("Unable to open file");
use strict; use warnings;
my $search_string = "Ball";
while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {

    last unless $row =~ /\S/;
    chomp $row;
    my @cells = split /\t/, $row;

    if ($cells[0] =~/$search_string/){
        print $cells[0];
    }
}
```

my test data file looks like this

```
Camera Make     Camera Model    Text    Ball    Swing
a       b       c       d       e
f       g       h       i       j
k       l       m       n       o
```

I am trying to see how this works before i use the actual test data file..

So how do I search for say "Ball" and have it return "d i n"

Comment: You're not asking to help with Perl. You're asking to write an assignment for you, since your code above has NOTHING to do with what your last line is asking for. Please write up an algorithm you're trying to implement in Perl and then ask why your Perl implementation doesn't work - currently, the answer to your question is "your code has nothing to do with what your task is"

Comment: I promise this isn't an assignment... but anyway ... How isn't this applicable.. I am defining what I am looking for and splitting the text by /\t/ which is tab i do believe and storing it in an array.. what I am asking is "how do i search that array and get the associated columns?

Comment: see the hint in my answer. You're parsing the file correctly; you're just not employing the logic/algorithm that solves your problem. The hint should be enough to get your ball rolling (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (DATA, "<test1.txt") or die ("Unable to open file");
my $search_string = "Ball";

my $header = <DATA>;
my @header_titles = split /\t/, $header;
my $extract_col = 0;

for my $header_line (@header_titles) {
  last if $header_line =~ m/$search_string/;
  $extract_col++;
}

print "Extracting column $extract_col\n";

while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
  last unless $row =~ /\S/;
  chomp $row;
  my @cells = split /\t/, $row;
  print "$cells[$extract_col] ";
}
```

Comment: This works... but I don't understand how you got it to do what it did... when you said 'my $header = <DATA>' that takes the file and puts it into the $header and then the @header titles you split the header file by tabs but wouldn't that put the column names in the rows and not columns?

Comment: @David: That is not how <> works.  In scalar context, it reads a single line from the file.  [Please read the I/O operators part of the perlop manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Comment: It would be nice practice if you **use** three argument [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Comment: @Nikhil: There is no advantage to using a harder-to-read syntax with a fixed file name, especially when I was attempting to mimic the style of the original code as much as possible.

Comment: @Con Yes there is. By using outdated pragmas you keep them alive. Always use the recommended three argument open, and you will never have a problem.

Comment: @TLP: It's not outdated if it works, is officially supported, and it's more clear what it's doing.  I use the three argument version when it's appropriate, like when there's a variable filename.  I am unconvinced that complicating the process of understanding for the question asker would somehow make this a better answer.

Comment: @Con You should not take criticism personally. StackOverflow is a place where people come to learn, therefore it is better to always use recommended programming techniques, even in cases such as this.

Comment: @TLP Although I appreciate you believe you are promoting a "best practice", I respectfully disagree, citing the explanation I've already provided.  Your lecturing on the ethos of the site is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @Con There really is no argument here. You are wrong in teaching inexperienced programmers poor programming practices. You might as well be excluding strict and warnings, and then in the comments be saying "I know what I'm doing!" It would still be poor programming practice, and you would still be guilty of reinforcing them.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't get any errors is because your program does exactly what you told it to (print all first column values that contain the string "Ball"). Since none of the cells in the first column contain that string, your program prints nothing.

Your problem is not with your Perl (it could use some minor stylistic improvement - specifically you're using obsolete form of `open()` - but is mostly fine), it's **with your algorithm**.

HINT: your first task in the algorithm should be finding WHICH column (by number) is the "Ball" column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw<first_index>;

my $column = first_index { $_ eq 'Ball' } split /\t/, <DATA>;
say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $column ], [ '*column' ] );
my @balls  = map { [split /\t/]->[$column] } <DATA>;
say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@balls ], [ '*balls' ] );
__DATA__
Camera Make Camera Model    Text    Ball    Swing
a   b   c   d   e
f   g   h   i   j
k   l   m   n   o
```

You would pretty much have to change the handle from `DATA` to some file you `open`-ed.

```
open( my $in, '<', '/path/to/data.file' ) 
    or die "Could not open file: $!"
    ;
```

And then substitute `<DATA>` for `<$in>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) to very conveniently extract the data for you. It might be overkill for your limited data, but it is a very solid solution.

Here I just use the **DATA** tag to contain the data, but if you prefer, you can replace that with a filehandle, such as `open my $fh, '<', 'text1.txt';` and change `*DATA` to `$fh`.

**Output:**

```
d i n
```

**Code:**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use autodie;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { sep_char => "\t" } );
my @list;
$csv->column_names ($csv->getline (*DATA));
while ( my $hr = $csv->getline_hr(*DATA) ) {
    push @list, $hr->{'Ball'};
}

print "@list\n";
__DATA__
Camera Make Camera Model    Text    Ball    Swing
a   b   c   d   e
f   g   h   i   j
k   l   m   n   o
```

ETA: If you're going to cut & paste to try it out, make sure that the tabs are carried over in the data.