# help parsing tab file and custom formatting in perl

Tags: perl

I have an output file that is `\t` delimited:

```
Data for 08/10/2011 
Host    QueueName   Queue-id    
test    123 Test Q  110
test    456 Test Q  120
test    789 Test Q  130
```

I'm looking to remove the first line (date) and then I want the 2nd line (header columns) to 
print out with the values like so as my final output file:

```
Host=test QueueName=123 Test Q Queue-id=110
Host=test QueueName=456 Test Q Queue-id=120
Host=test QueueName=789 Test Q Queue-id=130
```

What is a good way/practice to do this in perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS) for reading the file.

In this recent question, there was a similar problem: [How can I use Perl extract a particular column from a tab-separated file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7093571/725418) (See my answer)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use autodie;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { sep_char => "\t" } );
<DATA>;  # discard the first line
$csv->column_names ($csv->getline (*DATA));
my $hr = $csv->getline_hr_all(*DATA); 

for my $hashref (@$hr) {
    my @list;
    for my $key ($csv->column_names()) {
        push @list, join '=', $key, $hashref->{$key};
    }
    print "@list\n";
}
__DATA__
Data for 08/10/2011 
Host    QueueName   Queue-id    
test    123 Test Q  110
test    456 Test Q  120
test    789 Test Q  130
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I was able to successfully try your other example (using `getline_hr`) which you pointed out. I tried this code and apparently, i'm missing something. `Can't locate auto/Text/CSV_XS/getline_hr_.al in @INC`. Does that have to do with my version of perl? Thanks again.

Comment: No, if you can use `getline_hr` you can use `getline_hr_all`. That error looks pretty screwed up, though. `@INC` is where perl finds the modules. The functions are in the module. My guess is you made a typo in your code.