# How to only store certain column from input file?

Tags: perl, parsing

I am creating a script that should take in a data file and a column index, read and store that column and then perform some statistics on the data. I am unsure how to specify that I only want to store a specific column in Perl. Here is my code so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my ($FILE, $COLUMN_TO_PARSE) = @ARGV;

#check if file arg is present
if(not defined $FILE){
    die "Please specify file input $!";
} 
#check if column arg is present
if(not defined $COLUMN_TO_PARSE){
    die "Please specify column number $!";
}

unless(open(INPUT_FILE, "<", $FILE)){
        die "Couldn't open ", $FILE ," for reading!", $!;
}
my @data;
while(<INPUT_FILE>){
     # Only store $COLUMN_TO_PARSE, save to @data
}
close(INPUT_FILE);
```

For reference, the data coming in looks something like this(sorry for format):

01  8   0   35  0.64    22

02  8   0   37  0.68    9

03  8   0   49  0.68    49

So for example, if I ran

`perl descriptiveStatistics.pl dataFile.txt 3`

I would expect to have `[35,37,49]` in the `@data` array.

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093571/how-can-i-use-perl-extract-a-particular-column-from-a-tab-separated-file), but it has to do with headers which I don't have, and not very helpful imo. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean [35,37,49] ?

Comment: The answer given by Axeman in the article you linked to _this question_ provides the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `split()` to split the input into a list of records. By default, `split()` works on `$_` and splits on white space - which is exactly what we want here.

I've then used a list slice to get the column that you want, and pushed that onto your array.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# Check parameters
@ARGV == 2 or die "Please specify input file and column number\n";

my ($file, $column_to_parse) = @ARGV;

open my $in_fh, '<', $file
  or die "Couldn't open $file for reading: $!";

my @data;

while (<$in_fh>){
  push @data, (split)[$column_to_parse];
}
```

If I was writing it for myself, I think I would replace the `while` loop with a `map`.

```
my @data = map { (split)[$column_to_parse] } <$in_fh>;
```

**Update:** To ensure that you have been given a valid column number (and I think that's a good idea) you might write something like this:

```
while (<$in_fh>){
  my @fields = split;
  die "Not enough columns in row $.\n" if $#fields < $column_to_parse;
  push @data, $fields[$column_to_parse];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` is a good choice:

```
while (my $line = <INPUT_FILE>) {
    my @items = split(/\t/, $line);
    push @data,$items[$COLUMN_TO_PARSE];
}
```

Comment: If you use `while(<INPUT_FILE>)` and assign each record to `$_` then you can use `split`'s default behaviour and save a lot of typing - `my @items = split`. You could also eliminate the intermediate `@items` array - `push @data, (split)[$COLUMN_TO_PARSE]`

Comment: @DaveCross Good idea

Answer (score 0):

You could design a regexp pattern for matching a column, which you repeat `$COLUMN_TO_PARSE` times, and which then captures the content of the column and pushes it onto your array `@data`.

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data;
my $COLUMN_TO_PARSE = 3;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/([^\s]+\s+){$COLUMN_TO_PARSE}([^\s]+)/) {
        push @data, $2;
    } else {
        print("error wrong line format: $_\n");
    }
}
print Dumper(@data);

__DATA__
01 8 0 35 0.64 22
02 8 0 37 0.68 9
03 8 0 49 0.68 49
```

which gives the following dump for `@data`:

```
$VAR1 = '35';
$VAR2 = '37';
$VAR3 = '49';
```

`$COLUMN_TO_PARSE` is zero based, as in your example, and, as a side-effect, the regexp will fail if the requested column does not exist, thus giving you error-handling.

Comment: That all looks rather complicated. Wouldn't `split()` be far simpler?

Comment: @DaveCross: I guess I am a complicated person who wishes to make sure that when I intended to push something into an array, actually something is being pushed, especially when I take instructions from the user about a column number that is supposed to exist, or if I do not control the data source. `split` will not allow such control unless you make your code more "complicated" :-)

Comment: Checking for the existence of the requested column is a great idea and I commend you for posting the only solution that includes that check. But I maintain that adding that check to a `split`-based solution still makes for simpler code than your regex version. YMMV :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to get data column wise. Each column in stored in consecutive indices of the array.

```
while(<INPUT_FILE>){
     my @columns = split(/\t/, $_);  #Assuming delimiter to tab

     print "First column====$columns[0]\n";
     print "Second column====$columns[1]\n";

}
```

Do process whichever column you want and store into an array.

Comment: *You have to use `split`* - In Perl it's almost never true that you "have to use" any particular technique :-)